# How to format x-axis of date plots so that months are in letters

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have been trying to change the X-axis labels so that I see the months in letters e.g. 01 January or 01 Jan, rather than currently produced 01 01.

Is there a way to achieve it? I am plotting multiple datasets on a single chart by manipulating dates so they appear on a single chart, but they don't necessarily belong to the same year. Therefore, I have been trying to remove the year label, but the remainder month numbers are not looking nice.

```
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
from datetime import date
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def fig_formatter(ax):
    months = mdates.MonthLocator()
    myFmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%d/%m')
    ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(myFmt)
    plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
    plt.grid()
    ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(months)
    ax.xaxis.grid(True, 'major', linewidth=1)
    ax.xaxis.grid(True, 'minor', linewidth=0.5)

x_data = [date(2017, 1, 1), date(2017, 5, 1), date(2017, 12, 1)]
y_data = [5, 30, 10]
plt.plot_date(x_data, y_data, '-o')

ax = plt.subplot(111)
fig_formatter(ax)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Use `%b` for the month abbreviated, or `%B` for the full month's name. I guess that can be easily found out looking at [the datetime docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) and I suppose there are also already questions about this around on SO.

Comment: %b actually works, thanks! I can accept your response if you answer rather than a comment.

Comment: I already closed this question as duplicate. No need to accept anything here.